# Amnesia closes when loading

Tags: games, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad T410, Ubuntu 12.04 and Humble Bundle V. When I run amnesia it closes when loading.

I appreciate the help.

```
lucasa@lucasa:~$ ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
AL lib: alsa.c:512: Could not open playback device 'hw:0,0': Device or resource busy
*** glibc detected *** ./Amnesia.bin: malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x0c152020 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x73e42)[0xb6fd7e42]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75fbf)[0xb6fd9fbf]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_calloc+0xb6)[0xb6fdcd46]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so(hash_table_insert+0x46)[0xb5718416]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(_ZN10fs_visitor5visitEP11ir_variable+0xba)[0xb58d677a]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so(_ZN11ir_variable6acceptEP10ir_visitor+0x17)[0xb5502e27]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(_ZN10fs_visitor5visitEP11ir_function+0x95)[0xb58d66b5]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so(_ZN11ir_function6acceptEP10ir_visitor+0x17)[0xb5502e77]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(_ZN10fs_visitor3runEv+0x157)[0xb58d2cf7]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(brw_wm_fs_emit+0x35e)[0xb58d31fe]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(do_wm_prog+0x11e)[0xb58ab51e]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x5ac72)[0xb58abc72]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(brw_upload_state+0x14f)[0xb58a142f]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(brw_draw_prims+0x6d7)[0xb588c6f7]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so(+0x111f5d)[0xb56e9f5d]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so(+0x11233d)[0xb56ea33d]
./Amnesia.bin(_ZN3hpl20cVertexBufferOGL_VBO4DrawENS_21eVertexBufferDrawTypeE+0x54)[0x85c3784]
./Amnesia.bin(_ZN3hpl17cRendererDeferred23RenderLights_RenderBackEv+0x104)[0x841a794]
./Amnesia.bin(_ZN3hpl17cRendererDeferred12RenderLightsEv+0x138)[0x841c2f8]
./Amnesia.bin(_ZN3hpl17cRendererDeferred13RenderObjectsEv+0x191)[0x841eb41]
./Amnesia.bin(_ZN3hpl9iRenderer6RenderEfPNS_8cFrustumEPNS_6cWorldEPNS_15cRenderSettingsEPNS_13cRenderTargetEbPSt4listIPNS_17iRendererCallbackESaISB_EE+0x5c)[0x844323c]
./Amnesia.bin(_ZN3hpl6cScene6RenderEfj+0x11f)[0x845f5ff]
./Amnesia.bin(_ZN3hpl7cEngine3RunEv+0x2f7)[0x8569287]
./Amnesia.bin(_Z7hplMainRKSs+0x44)[0x82b68f4]
./Amnesia.bin(main+0x14d)[0x854fe8d]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb6f7d4d3]
./Amnesia.bin(ftell+0x45)[0x8198441]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08858000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 34958      /opt/Amnesia/Amnesia.bin
08858000-0885d000 rw-p 00810000 08:01 34958      /opt/Amnesia/Amnesia.bin
0885d000-0886f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
095be000-0c6a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
a7e00000-a7ec3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a7ec3000-a7f00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
a9db9000-a9f39000 rw-s 254c7000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
aa2bb000-aa43b000 rw-s 265bb000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
aa43b000-aa5bb000 rw-s 2643b000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
aa5bb000-aa73b000 rw-s 262bb000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
aa73b000-aa73c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
aa73c000-aaf3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
aaf3c000-aaf3d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
aaf3d000-ab73d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ab73d000-ab73e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ab73e000-abf3e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
abf3e000-abf9e000 rw-s 24270000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
abf9e000-abffe000 rw-s 24210000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
abfff000-b0000000 rw-s 00000000 00:12 39317      /run/shm/pulse-shm-1564699572
b0000000-b0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b0021000-b0100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b01dd000-b035d000 rw-s 2613b000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b035d000-b035e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b035e000-b0b5e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b0b5e000-b0f5e000 rw-s 25d3b000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b0f5f000-b0fcf000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40547      /drm mm object (deleted)
b0fcf000-b103f000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40511      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1108000-b1140000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40554      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1140000-b1300000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40485      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1300000-b1381000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b1381000-b1400000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b1420000-b1500000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40484      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1500000-b15c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b15c1000-b1600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b161a000-b1622000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 35516      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1622000-b17a2000 rw-s 25bbb000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b17c6000-b17fe000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40546      /drm mm object (deleted)
b17fe000-b1836000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40486      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1839000-b183d000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40574      /drm mm object (deleted)
b183d000-b1841000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40573      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1841000-b1848000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40572      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1848000-b184f000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40571      /drm mm object (deleted)
b184f000-b185d000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40555      /drm mm object (deleted)
b185d000-b186b000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40548      /drm mm object (deleted)
b186b000-b1887000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40533      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1887000-b18b7000 rw-s 25647000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b18c8000-b18c9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b18c9000-b18ca000 rw-s 26740000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b18ca000-b18cb000 rw-s 2673f000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b18cb000-b18cc000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40727      /drm mm object (deleted)
b18cc000-b18cd000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40724      /drm mm object (deleted)
b18cd000-b18dd000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 38152      /drm mm object (deleted)
b18dd000-b18ed000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 35519      /drm mm object (deleted)
b18ed000-b18ee000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 38153      /drm mm object (deleted)
b18ee000-b18ef000 rw-s 2673e000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b18ef000-b18f0000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40726      /drm mm object (deleted)
b18f0000-b18f1000 rw-s 2673d000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b18f1000-b18f2000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40723      /drm mm object (deleted)
b18f2000-b18f3000 rw-s 2673c000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b18f3000-b18f4000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40720      /drm mm object (deleted)
b18f4000-b18f5000 rw-s 2673b000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b18f5000-b18f6000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40718      /drm mm object (deleted)
b18f6000-b18f7000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40717      /drm mm object (deleted)
b18f7000-b18f8000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40716      /drm mm object (deleted)
b18f8000-b1908000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 35515      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1908000-b1924000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40704      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1924000-b1928000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40703      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1928000-b192f000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40696      /drm mm object (deleted)
b192f000-b194b000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40695      /drm mm object (deleted)
b194b000-b1967000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40694      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1967000-b1975000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40680      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1975000-b1977000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40673      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1977000-b197b000 rw-s 256a7000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b197b000-b197f000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40671      /drm mm object (deleted)
b197f000-b1980000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40666      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1980000-b198e000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40659      /drm mm object (deleted)
b198e000-b199c000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40658      /drm mm object (deleted)
b199c000-b19b8000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40657      /drm mm object (deleted)
b19b8000-b19c6000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40656      /drm mm object (deleted)
b19c6000-b1ac6000 rw-s 253bb000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b1ac7000-b1ace000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40705      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1ace000-b1aea000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40520      /drm mm object (deleted)
b1aea000-b1b1a000 rw-s 25677000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b1b1a000-b1c1c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b1c1c000-b1d9c000 rw-s 2523b000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b1d9c000-b219c000 rw-s 257bb000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b219c000-b21a4000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40406      /drm mm object (deleted)
b21a4000-b2204000 rw-s 251db000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b2204000-b2264000 rw-s 2517b000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b2264000-b22c4000 rw-s 2511b000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b22c4000-b2324000 rw-s 250bb000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b2324000-b2384000 rw-s 2505b000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b2384000-b23e4000 rw-s 24ffb000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b23e4000-b2444000 rw-s 24f3b000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b2444000-b24a4000 rw-s 244c7000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b24a5000-b26a7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b26ac000-b26e4000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40510      /drm mm object (deleted)
b26e4000-b27e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b27e5000-b2845000 rw-s 24467000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b2845000-b28a5000 rw-s 24407000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b28a6000-b2906000 rw-s 2431c000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b2906000-b291e000 rw-s 24304000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b291e000-b2936000 rw-s 242ec000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b2936000-b294e000 rw-s 242d4000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b294e000-b2952000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40449      /drm mm object (deleted)
b2952000-b2956000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40448      /drm mm object (deleted)
b2956000-b295a000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40447      /drm mm object (deleted)
b295a000-b295e000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40446      /drm mm object (deleted)
b295e000-b2962000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40445      /drm mm object (deleted)
b2962000-b2966000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40444      /drm mm object (deleted)
b2966000-b296a000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40443      /drm mm object (deleted)
b296a000-b296e000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40442      /drm mm object (deleted)
b296e000-b2c71000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b2c72000-b2c80000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40512      /drm mm object (deleted)
b2c80000-b2c9c000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40501      /drm mm object (deleted)
b2c9c000-b2c9d000 rw-s 2437c000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b2c9d000-b2cfd000 rw-s 24f9b000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b2cfd000-b2eff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b2eff000-b2f00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b2f00000-b3700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b3700000-b3721000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b3721000-b3800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b3800000-b3801000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40619      /drm mm object (deleted)
b3801000-b3805000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40588      /drm mm object (deleted)
b3805000-b380c000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40581      /drm mm object (deleted)
b380c000-b381a000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40500      /drm mm object (deleted)
b381a000-b381e000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40477      /drm mm object (deleted)
b381e000-b383a000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40476      /drm mm object (deleted)
b383a000-b3848000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40475      /drm mm object (deleted)
b3848000-b3854000 rw-s 254bb000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b3854000-b385c000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 38154      /drm mm object (deleted)
b385c000-b385d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b385d000-b405d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b405d000-b405e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b405e000-b40de000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b40de000-b4109000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 398258     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_bluetooth.so
b4109000-b410a000 r--p 0002a000 08:01 398258     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_bluetooth.so
b410a000-b410c000 rw-p 0002b000 08:01 398258     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_bluetooth.so
b410c000-b4117000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 264354     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
b4117000-b4118000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 264354     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
b4118000-b4119000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 264354     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
b4119000-b4123000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 264358     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
b4123000-b4124000 r--p 00009000 08:01 264358     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
b4124000-b4125000 rw-p 0000a000 08:01 264358     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
b4125000-b4167000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 397980     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0.1.0
b4167000-b4168000 ---p 00042000 08:01 397980     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0.1.0
b4168000-b4169000 r--p 00042000 08:01 397980     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0.1.0
b4169000-b416a000 rw-p 00043000 08:01 397980     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0.1.0
b416a000-b4196000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 398102     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0
b4196000-b4197000 r--p 0002b000 08:01 398102     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0
b4197000-b4198000 rw-p 0002c000 08:01 398102     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0
b4198000-b4199000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4199000-b4999000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4999000-b49b1000 rw-s 241f8000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b49b1000-b49b2000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40407      /drm mm object (deleted)
b49b2000-b49b3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b49b3000-b49b4000 rw-s 241f2000 00:05 3233       /dev/dri/card0
b49b4000-b54bb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b54bb000-b55d0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 401382     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so
b55d0000-b55d5000 r--p 00114000 08:01 401382     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so
b55d5000-b55d7000 rw-p 00119000 08:01 401382     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/libglsl.so
b55d7000-b55d8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b55d8000-b5833000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 401383     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
b5833000-b5834000 ---p 0025b000 08:01 401383     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
b5834000-b583a000 r--p 0025b000 08:01 401383     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
b583a000-b583c000 rw-p 00261000 08:01 401383     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/libdricore.so
b583c000-b5851000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5851000-b592b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 401378     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
b592b000-b592d000 r--p 000d9000 08:01 401378     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
b592d000-b592f000 rw-p 000db000 08:01 401378     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
b592f000-b5a2e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5a2e000-b5a2f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5a2f000-b6269000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6269000-b626d000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 40502      /drm mm object (deleted)
b626d000-b629f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 431535     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0.0.0
b629f000-b62a0000 r--p 00031000 08:01 431535     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0.0.0
b62a0000-b62a1000 rw-p 00032000 08:01 431535     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0.0.0
b62a1000-b62aa000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 398082     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.0
b62aa000-b62ab000 r--p 00008000 08:01 398082     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.0
b62ab000-b62ac000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 398082     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.0
b62ac000-b62c9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 397807     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
b62c9000-b62ca000 r--p 0001c000 08:01 397807     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
b62ca000-b62cb000 rw-p 0001d000 08:01 397807     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
b62cb000-b62d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 397653     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
```